# How to run servlet on tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I have create following java file,compile it and got .class file.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>First Example</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
}
}
```

Now i created directory abc/WEB-INF/classes under apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps directory
so my classFile Path is : apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/abc/WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorld.class
and trying to access http://localhost:8080/abc/WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorld, but getting error 
"The requested resource (/abc/HelloWorld) is not available"

Where i am going wrong? or should i have to specify other configuration?

Comment: http://pdf.coreservlets.com/ Try giving this book a read. You wont be able to access anything inside your WEB-INF directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your servlet in your `web.xml`.

Answer (score 25):

you must define your servlet in the `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>yourpackage.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

and then define the mapping from URL to servlet

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and finally type the URL as:
`http://localhost:8080/abc/HelloWorld`